# how do i keep padding for cleared float

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have images inside a div that are floating left to right, top to bottom, 2 per row. I don't want a 2-column layout because I want the images' flow to be maintained if I add, subtract or replace some. Sometimes if an image on the right side is smaller than the one on the left, I don't want the next one to float underneath the one on the right but rather to bump to the next line.

If I add "clear: left" to that image, the padding doesn't work - I guess because it's cleared?  How can I maintain the padding for those images so they don't hug right up against the edge of the div?

The problem is evident in the 3rd and 5th images reading left to right, top to bottom.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.img-zoom').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('transition');
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('transition');
  });
});
```

```css
#main {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#article {
  width: 450px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 75px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}
#article p {
  text-indent: 50px;
}
#gallery {
  width: 360px;  
  height: 3600px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #F8F1D4;
}
div.imageBlockFull {
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 20px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
}
IMG.displayed {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto 
}
div.imageBlockLeft {
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 20px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}    
div.imageBlockRight {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 0px;   
  width: 150px;
  float: right;
}
div.imageBlockFloatLeftClearLeft {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 0px;   
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
div.imageBlockLeft p:nth-child(2n+2) {
  font-family: "jaf-bernina-sans-narrow";
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 18px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #F8F1D4;
}
div.imageBlockRight p:nth-child(2n+2) {
  font-family: "jaf-bernina-sans-narrow";
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 18px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #F8F1D4;
}
.captionFull {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 20px;
  padding: 0px 20px;   
  font-family: "jaf-bernina-sans-narrow";
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 18px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #F8F1D4;
}
.captionFull  p {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
p.centerHover {
  font-family: "jaf-bernina-sans-narrow";
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 0 1em 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 16em;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  border-top: 2px solid #E3A300 !important;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #E3A300 !important;
}
/*THIS AFFECTS THE SPEED OF THE ZOOM*/
.img-zoom {
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
/*THIS AFFECTS THE SIZE OF THE ZOOM*/
.transition {
  -webkit-transform: scale(4.5); 
  -moz-transform: scale(4.5);
  -o-transform: scale(4.5);
  transform: scale(4.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="article">
    <p>I am descended from two unrelated Lewis lines - on my mother's and father's side.  This page is devoted to my paternal Lewis line.</p>
    <p>My earliest known Lewis ancestor in this line is Alexander, born about 1750 and died sometime between 12 Apr 1819 and 10 Sep 1820. He was in Christian County, Kentucky, by 15 May 1798, at a session of the County Court. He received warrant #725 to survey 200 acres of “second rate land” on the west fork of Pond River on 19 Oct 1798. A survey was conducted on 12 Feb 1799.  Alexander assigned the survey to Benjamin P Campbell on 1 May 1805 and Campbell assigned it to Smith Lofland on 13 Nov 1806.  On 17 Dec 1805, Alexander's son, Robert, assigned him 200 acres on Pond River.  Alexander disappears from records until 29 Apr 1818, when Robert assigned him another 200 acres on Pond River. In an indenture (deed) dated 10 Sep 1820, Christian County Commissioner James W Callaway sells the "the heirs of Alexander Lewis&#91's&#93" interest in 200 acres issuing from his warrant #725 to Smith Lofland.  The indenture states a follows:</p>
  </div>
  <div id="gallery">
    <h1>Image Gallery</h1>
    <p class="centerHover">Hover over images to enlarge.</p>
    <div class="imageBlockLeft">
      <p><img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_robert_e.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land warrant" width="148" height="195"></p>
      <p>My great-grandfather, Robert Ewing Lewis, ca. 1908.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageBlockRight">
      <p><img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_gene.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land warrant" width="148" height="184"></p>
      <p>My grandfather, Eugene Barton Lewis, ca. 1926.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageBlockFloatLeftClearLeft">
      <p><img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_jim.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land warrant" width="149" height="225"></p>
      <p>My father, James Edward Lewis, ca. 1959.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageBlockRight">
      <p><img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_4_generations.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land warrant" width="143" height="104"></p>
      <p>Four generations:  Thompson Price Lewis, Robert Ewing Lewis holding James Edward Lewis, Eugene Barton Lewis, Jan 1939.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageBlockFloatLeftClearLeft">
      <p><img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_alex_17981019_ky_christian_war_1197.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land warrant" width="140" height="143"></p>
      <p>Fig. 1.  Alexander Lewis's warrant #3663 to survey 200 acres of "second rate land" on the west fork of Pond River, dated 19 Oct 1798.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageBlockRight">
      <p><img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_alex_17990212_ky_christian_sur_1197.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land survey" width="147" height="256"></p> 
      <p>Alexander Lewis's survey #1197 dated 12 Feb 1799 for warrant #3663.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageBlockLeft">
      <p><img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_alex_18050501_ky_christian_trn_1197.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land transfer" width="146" height="256"></p>
      <p>Alexander Lewis transferred his survey #1197 to Benjamin P Campbell on 1 May 1805.  Campbell transferred it to Smith Lofland on 13 Nov 1806.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageBlockRight">
      <p><img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_alex_&_robt_18020809_ky_christian_war_14849.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land warrant" width="143" height="118"></p>
      <p>Robert Lewis's warrant #725 for 200 acres dated 9 Aug 1802.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageBlockLeft">
      <p><img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_alex_&_robt_18051217_ky_christian_war_14849_obv.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land warrant" width="143" height="121"></p>
      <p>Robert Lewis transferred warrant #725 to his father on 17 Dec 1805.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageBlockLeft">
      <p><img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_smith_lofland_v_heirs_1.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land transfer" width="143" height="84"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageBlockRight">
      <p><img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_smith_lofland_v_heirs_2.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land transfer" width="142" height="184"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="captionFull">
      <p>Smith Lofland's suit against the heirs of Alexander Lewis.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- THIS IS THE END OF THE HTML -->
```

Comment: can you clear little bit more , its hard to understand but you want to do ?

Comment: You can rework your site a bit and just add `<br>` elements to be quick and dirty... here's a minimal demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3fxnn4y6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have change the padding of `div.imageBlockFloatLeftClearLeft` right to left

```
div.imageBlockFloatLeftClearLeft {
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

is this what you need please check the below snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.img-zoom').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('transition');

  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('transition');
  });
});
```

```css
#main {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#article {
  width: 450px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 75px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}
#article p {
  text-indent: 50px;
}
#gallery {
  width: 360px;
  height: 3600px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #F8F1D4;
}
div.imageBlockFull {
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 20px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
}
IMG.displayed {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto
}
div.imageBlockLeft {
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 20px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}
div.imageBlockRight {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 0px;
  width: 150px;
  float: right;
}
div.imageBlockFloatLeftClearLeft {
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 20px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
div.imageBlockLeft p:nth-child(2n+2) {
  font-family: "jaf-bernina-sans-narrow";
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 18px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #F8F1D4;
}
div.imageBlockRight p:nth-child(2n+2) {
  font-family: "jaf-bernina-sans-narrow";
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 18px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #F8F1D4;
}
.captionFull {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 20px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  font-family: "jaf-bernina-sans-narrow";
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 18px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #F8F1D4;
}
.captionFull p {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
p.centerHover {
  font-family: "jaf-bernina-sans-narrow";
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 0 1em 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 16em;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  border-top: 2px solid #E3A300 !important;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #E3A300 !important;
}
/*THIS AFFECTS THE SPEED OF THE ZOOM*/

.img-zoom {
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
/*THIS AFFECTS THE SIZE OF THE ZOOM*/

.transition {
  -webkit-transform: scale(4.5);
  -moz-transform: scale(4.5);
  -o-transform: scale(4.5);
  transform: scale(4.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="article">
    <p>I am descended from two unrelated Lewis lines - on my mother's and father's side. This page is devoted to my paternal Lewis line.</p>
    <p>My earliest known Lewis ancestor in this line is Alexander, born about 1750 and died sometime between 12 Apr 1819 and 10 Sep 1820. He was in Christian County, Kentucky, by 15 May 1798, at a session of the County Court. He received warrant #725 to
      survey 200 acres of “second rate land” on the west fork of Pond River on 19 Oct 1798. A survey was conducted on 12 Feb 1799. Alexander assigned the survey to Benjamin P Campbell on 1 May 1805 and Campbell assigned it to Smith Lofland on 13 Nov 1806.
      On 17 Dec 1805, Alexander's son, Robert, assigned him 200 acres on Pond River. Alexander disappears from records until 29 Apr 1818, when Robert assigned him another 200 acres on Pond River. In an indenture (deed) dated 10 Sep 1820, Christian County
      Commissioner James W Callaway sells the "the heirs of Alexander Lewis&#91's&#93" interest in 200 acres issuing from his warrant #725 to Smith Lofland. The indenture states a follows:</p>
  </div>
  <div id="gallery">
    <h1>Image Gallery</h1>
    <p class="centerHover">Hover over images to enlarge.</p>
    <div class="imageBlockLeft">
      <p>
        <img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_robert_e.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land warrant" width="148" height="195">
      </p>
      <p>My great-grandfather, Robert Ewing Lewis, ca. 1908.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageBlockRight">
      <p>
        <img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_gene.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land warrant" width="148" height="184">
      </p>
      <p>My grandfather, Eugene Barton Lewis, ca. 1926.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageBlockFloatLeftClearLeft">
      <p>
        <img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_jim.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land warrant" width="149" height="225">
      </p>
      <p>My father, James Edward Lewis, ca. 1959.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageBlockRight">
      <p>
        <img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_4_generations.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land warrant" width="143" height="104">
      </p>
      <p>Four generations: Thompson Price Lewis, Robert Ewing Lewis holding James Edward Lewis, Eugene Barton Lewis, Jan 1939.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageBlockFloatLeftClearLeft">
      <p>
        <img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_alex_17981019_ky_christian_war_1197.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land warrant" width="140" height="143">
      </p>
      <p>Fig. 1. Alexander Lewis's warrant #3663 to survey 200 acres of "second rate land" on the west fork of Pond River, dated 19 Oct 1798.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageBlockRight">
      <p>
        <img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_alex_17990212_ky_christian_sur_1197.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land survey" width="147" height="256">
      </p>
      <p>Alexander Lewis's survey #1197 dated 12 Feb 1799 for warrant #3663.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageBlockLeft">
      <p>
        <img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_alex_18050501_ky_christian_trn_1197.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land transfer" width="146" height="256">
      </p>
      <p>Alexander Lewis transferred his survey #1197 to Benjamin P Campbell on 1 May 1805. Campbell transferred it to Smith Lofland on 13 Nov 1806.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageBlockRight">
      <p>
        <img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_alex_&_robt_18020809_ky_christian_war_14849.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land warrant" width="143" height="118">
      </p>
      <p>Robert Lewis's warrant #725 for 200 acres dated 9 Aug 1802.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageBlockLeft">
      <p>
        <img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_alex_&_robt_18051217_ky_christian_war_14849_obv.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land warrant" width="143" height="121">
      </p>
      <p>Robert Lewis transferred warrant #725 to his father on 17 Dec 1805.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageBlockLeft">
      <p>
        <img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_smith_lofland_v_heirs_1.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land transfer" width="143" height="84">
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageBlockRight">
      <p>
        <img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_smith_lofland_v_heirs_2.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land transfer" width="142" height="184">
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="captionFull">
      <p>Smith Lofland's suit against the heirs of Alexander Lewis.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I marked this answer as correct as it was the only one that reproduced the code snippet when I copied it into my code.  I am sure the others worked but for some reason when I tried to reproduce the code the 3rd image ("pg_p_lewis_jim.jpg") kept falling under the 2nd on the right.  I also liked the fact that a minimum of revision was required.  I don't understand why 2 people are shown under the solution - Abhishek and Naila - one as "edited" and one as "answered."  Who gets credit?  Just curious.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) library and sleep well about this issue; The image positions will be handled dynamically; My Sample: https://jsfiddle.net/2g31njbe/

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="article">
    <p>I am descended from two unrelated Lewis lines - on my mother's and father's side.  This page is devoted to my paternal Lewis line.</p>
    <p>My earliest known Lewis ancestor in this line is Alexander, born about 1750 and died sometime between 12 Apr 1819 and 10 Sep 1820. He was in Christian County, Kentucky, by 15 May 1798, at a session of the County Court. He received warrant #725 to survey 200 acres of “second rate land” on the west fork of Pond River on 19 Oct 1798. A survey was conducted on 12 Feb 1799.  Alexander assigned the survey to Benjamin P Campbell on 1 May 1805 and Campbell assigned it to Smith Lofland on 13 Nov 1806.  On 17 Dec 1805, Alexander's son, Robert, assigned him 200 acres on Pond River.  Alexander disappears from records until 29 Apr 1818, when Robert assigned him another 200 acres on Pond River. In an indenture (deed) dated 10 Sep 1820, Christian County Commissioner James W Callaway sells the "the heirs of Alexander Lewis&#91's&#93" interest in 200 acres issuing from his warrant #725 to Smith Lofland.  The indenture states a follows:</p>
  </div>
  <div id="gallery">
    <h1>Image Gallery</h1>
    <p class="centerHover">Hover over images to enlarge.</p>
    <div class="grid-wrap">
        <div class="imageBlockLeft grid-item"><p><img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_robert_e.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land warrant" width="148" height="195"></p>
          <p>My great-grandfather, Robert Ewing Lewis, ca. 1908.</p></div>
        <div class="imageBlockRight grid-item"><p><img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_gene.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land warrant" width="148" height="184"></p>
          <p>My grandfather, Eugene Barton Lewis, ca. 1926.</p></div>
        <div class="imageBlockLeft grid-item"><p><img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_jim.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land warrant" width="149" height="225"></p>
          <p>My father, James Edward Lewis, ca. 1959.</p></div>
        <div class="imageBlockRight grid-item"><p><img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_4_generations.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land warrant" width="143" height="104"></p>
          <p>Four generations:  Thompson Price Lewis, Robert Ewing Lewis holding James Edward Lewis, Eugene Barton Lewis, Jan 1939.</p></div>
        <div class="imageBlockLeft grid-item"><p><img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_alex_17981019_ky_christian_war_1197.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land warrant" width="140" height="143"></p>
          <p>Fig. 1.  Alexander Lewis's warrant #3663 to survey 200 acres of "second rate land" on the west fork of Pond River, dated 19 Oct 1798.</p></div>
        <div class="imageBlockRight grid-item"><p><img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_alex_17990212_ky_christian_sur_1197.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land survey" width="147" height="256"></p> 
          <p>Alexander Lewis's survey #1197 dated 12 Feb 1799 for warrant #3663.</p></div>
        <div class="imageBlockLeft grid-item"><p><img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_alex_18050501_ky_christian_trn_1197.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land transfer" width="146" height="256"></p>
          <p>Alexander Lewis transferred his survey #1197 to Benjamin P Campbell on 1 May 1805.  Campbell transferred it to Smith Lofland on 13 Nov 1806.</p></div>
        <div class="imageBlockRight grid-item"><p><img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_alex_&_robt_18020809_ky_christian_war_14849.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land warrant" width="143" height="118"></p>
          <p>Robert Lewis's warrant #725 for 200 acres dated 9 Aug 1802.</p></div>
        <div class="imageBlockLeft grid-item"><p><img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_alex_&_robt_18051217_ky_christian_war_14849_obv.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land warrant" width="143" height="121"></p>
          <p>Robert Lewis transferred warrant #725 to his father on 17 Dec 1805.</p></div>
        <div class="imageBlockRight grid-item"><p><img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_smith_lofland_v_heirs_1.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land transfer" width="143" height="84"></p></div>
        <div class="imageBlockLeft grid-item"><p><img class="img-zoom" src=http://bartonlewis.com/_images/pg_p_lewis_smith_lofland_v_heirs_2.jpg class="img-thumbnail" alt="lewis land transfer" width="142" height="184"></p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="captionFull"><p>Smith Lofland's suit against the heirs of Alexander Lewis.</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- THIS IS THE END OF THE HTML -->
```

**CSS:**

```
#main {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#article {
  width: 450px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 75px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}
#article p {
  text-indent: 50px;
}
#gallery {
  width: 340px;
  padding:0 10px;
  //height: 3600px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #F8F1D4;
}
.grid-wrap{width:100%; position:relative}
.grid-item{z-index:1}
.grid-item:hover{z-index:2}
div.imageBlockFull {
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 20px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
}
IMG.displayed {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto 
}
div.imageBlockLeft {
  padding:10px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  //clear:left;
}    
div.imageBlockRight {
  padding:10px;
  width: 150px;
  float: right;
  //clear:right;
}
div.imageBlockFloatLeftClearLeft {
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 0px;   
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
div.imageBlockLeft p:nth-child(2n+2) {
  font-family: "jaf-bernina-sans-narrow";
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 18px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #F8F1D4;
}
div.imageBlockRight p:nth-child(2n+2) {
  font-family: "jaf-bernina-sans-narrow";
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 18px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #F8F1D4;
}
.captionFull {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 20px;
  padding: 0px 20px;   
  font-family: "jaf-bernina-sans-narrow";
  font-size: .8em;
  line-height: 18px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #F8F1D4;
}
.captionFull  p {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
p.centerHover {
  font-family: "jaf-bernina-sans-narrow";
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 0 1em 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 16em;
  text-align: center;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 11px;
  border-top: 2px solid #E3A300 !important;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #E3A300 !important;
}
/*THIS AFFECTS THE SPEED OF THE ZOOM*/
.img-zoom {
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
/*THIS AFFECTS THE SIZE OF THE ZOOM*/
.transition {
  -webkit-transform: scale(4.5); 
  -moz-transform: scale(4.5);
  -o-transform: scale(4.5);
  transform: scale(4.5);
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $('.img-zoom').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('transition');
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('transition');
  });

  $('.grid-wrap').masonry({
    //gutter: 10,
    itemSelector: '.grid-item'
  });
});
```